# How to set uuid as default primary key on MySql 8 "Collection" Table

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-8.0

I have the following table to use as a "NoSQL Collection" on MySQL 8:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `doc` json DEFAULT NULL,
    `_id` varbinary(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`doc`,_utf8mb4'$._id'))) STORED NOT NULL,
    `_json_schema` json GENERATED ALWAYS AS (_utf8mb4'{"type":"object"}') VIRTUAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `$val_strict` CHECK (json_schema_valid(`_json_schema`,`doc`)) /*!80016 NOT ENFORCED */
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I would like to use UUID as a primary key, something like this:

```
`_id` varbinary(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE)),
```

The problem is that I don't know how to keep the same _id field replicated inside the json doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to define a trigger to set the JSON field according to the new primary key.

Demo:

```
mysql> create trigger t before insert on users for each row 
  set NEW.doc = JSON_SET(COALESCE(NEW.doc, '{}'), '$._id', NEW._id);
```

I use COALESCE() just in case the `NEW.doc` is NULL. That would cause JSON_SET() to return NULL, so I make sure the doc is at least an empty object.

```
mysql> insert into users () values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+
| doc                                               | _id                                | _json_schema       |
+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+
| {"_id": "base64:type15:6JKSilV9Ee2XvnTAaMWl7A=="} | 0xE892928A557D11ED97BE74C068C5A5EC | {"type": "object"} |
+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

However, I have to comment that it's superfluous to store the `_id` in both a normal column and in the JSON doc.